# Select from two tables based on values of one of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

1) Table1 say table1 with structure as :

`moduleID | moduleName 
   10    |      XYZ
   20    |      PQR
   30    |      ABC`

2) Table2 say table2 with structure as :

`moduleID | Level | Value 
   10    |   1    |  20
   10    |   2    |  30
   30    |   3    |  40
   10    |   3    |  50
   20    |   2    |  30`

`moduleID` being primary key in table1,and value of the column `level` can have values 1 to 3.
Now it is required to display the data as follows :

`moduleID | moduleName | Level1  | Level2  | Level3 
   10    |      XYZ    | 20      |  30   |   50
   20    |      PQR    | NULL    |  30   |   NULL
   30    |      ABC    | NULL    |  NULL |   50`

In simpler terms, values of column `Level` in table2 is displayed as Level1, Level2 and Level3 and values corresponding to each level is populated in the corresponding `moduleID` row.
Any help on this? beginner here in SQL. Something to do with Views?

Comment: It's a crosstab or pivot, but more simply solved (easily scalable) in application code (e.g. a PHP loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select t1.moduleID, t1.moduleName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN Value END) Level1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN Value END) Level2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN Value END) Level3
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.moduleID = t2.moduleID
group by t1.moduleID, t1.moduleName
```

Comment: what if the values of column Level in table2 are not fixed ,..as mentioned in the question .. can take 1 to 10 values (which actually is the scenario)..is there a better way ..a more generalized method?

Comment: @lazyrabbit You can use as many conditionals as you like. If the number of levels is dynamic, then you have to use dynamic sql and prepared statements.

Comment: a example would be extremely helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this all process it will work fine for your expected answer.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(moduleName VARCHAR(50),moduleID INT)
GO
--Populate Sample records
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('.NET',10)
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('Java',20)
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('SQL',30)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(moduleID INT,[Level] INT,Value INT)
GO
--Populate Sample records
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(10,1,20)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(10,2,30)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(30,3,40)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(10,3,50)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(20,2,30)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(20,4,60)
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_tabledata]
AS
SELECT t1.[moduleID],[moduleName]
      ,[Level]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [db_Sample].[dbo].[Table2] t2 inner join [db_Sample].[dbo].[Table1] t1 on t1.[moduleID] = t2.[moduleID]
GO







DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([Level])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Level] FROM Table2) AS [Level]

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT moduleID,moduleName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM [vw_tabledata] 
    PIVOT(MAX(Value) 
          FOR [Level] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: as i commented on previous answer, any generalized method if the values of level column can go upto max 10. ??Thanks

Comment: Refer this answer, its modified.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` for each Level in table 2.

```
select t1.*, t2_l1.value as Level1, t2_l2.value as Level2, t2_l3.value as Level3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2_l1 on t1.moduleID = t2_l1.moduleID and t2_l1.Level = 'Level1'
left join table2 t2_l2 on t1.moduleID = t2_l2.moduleID and t2_l2.Level = 'Level2'
left join table2 t2_l3 on t1.moduleID = t2_l3.moduleID and t2_l3.Level = 'Level3'
```

If a moduleID has several different values for a level, all of them will be returned. (If you want the sum instead, take a look at Giorgos Betsos' answer.)

Comment: what if the values of column Level in table2 are not fixed ,..as mentioned in the question .. can take 1 to 10 values (which actually is the scenario)..is there a better way ?

Comment: Do you mean you can have any number of different levels,  e.g. Level 17 and Level 79?

Comment: no..max up to 10. adding left joins won't be a nice practice.

Comment: I understand. And what's the expected result if a moduleid has several values for one level?